# Redirecting from subdomain to query string

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There is a list of options in my website home page - for example, http://example.com. When a user clicks on option1, I want to show the URL as http://option1.example.com and not http://example.com/xyz.php?opt=option1. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have infinite number of sub-domains ? Because if that no of such "option1" is limited, you can hard code the links

Comment: @Prashant Singh - Thanks for quick response. I have limited options.

Comment: create required  number of sub-domains then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to create a subdomain for each option and then provide the required code at that subdomain.  how you set that up varies by hosting provider.

Do you really need a seperate subdomain per option?

Could you use `http://abc.ca/Option1/` or `http://abc.ca/Options/1/` instead?

If not you will need to contact your hosting providers about creating subdomains option1.abc.ca etc and where to put your php pages.

If you are hosting your own server with apache, I think it is possible to use a * dns entry to accept all subdomains and then you can use $_SERVER variables to get the domain being requested.

Comment: Thank you, @Toby Allen. I think creating sub domains for every option is a better solution.